# What is considered a side quest?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

For the `Weaving a Tapestry` trophy, I need to complete 80 side quests. What exactly is considered a side quest in this game? I feel like Hunts aren't considered side quests, as I've definitely done enough that I should've at least earned `Spinning a Yarn IV` for completing 40 side quests.

Do tours with party members after camping count as side quests? What about events like encountering people with broken down cars? Do photo ops that Prompto mentions while driving count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this guide](http://www.powerpyx.com/final-fantasy-xv-trophy-guide-roadmap/), any quest colored blue counts as a side quest:

> There are far more than 80 sidequests. In your quest list they are shown in blue color.

Thus, hunts (yellow) and tours (green) do **not** count as side quests. Photo ops and helping people on the side of the road *are* side quests, however.

Comment: This was going to be my answer. I finished that trophy extremely early because i was doing every side quest i came across. upvote

Comment: @Mayshar I'd actually thought the tours counted as side quests. The hunts seemed not to count as side quests, seeing as I did about 10 before I got the trophy for doing 10 side quests.